# Bitcoin related research areas

Tags: alternatives, cryptography, proof-of-work, proof-of-stake, academic-research

I have a one year research project in my MSc curriculum. So i was suppose to address a existing issue in bitcoin protocol. Highly appreciate if someone can advise me and give me some ideas.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Selfish mining](http://hackingdistributed.com/2013/11/04/bitcoin-is-broken/) is probably one of the most addressed issues that was theorized by a group at Cornell university. I find this interesting, because rather than being a technical issue such as [transaction malleability](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction_Malleability), it is more of a conceptual issue with how Bitcoin and its consensus system works.

That should get you started and give you some food for thought.